# Concave shape boundary

Tags: css, svg, hover, css-shapes

I am trying to create this shape in CSS/SVG: [image]

The problem is that white portion need to be transparent. How do I do that in CSS/SVG? I also need hover on shape.

```css
#shape {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#circle1,
#circle2,
#circle3,
#circle4 {
  background: white;
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
#circle1 {
  top: -200px;
  right: -340px;
}
#circle2 {
  top: -1000px;
  left: -740px;
}
#circle3 {
  top: -2350px;
  left: -200px;
}
#circle4 {
  top: -2050px;
  left: -200px;
}
#shape:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="shape">
  <div id="circle1">
  </div>
  <div id="circle2">
  </div>
  <div id="circle3">
  </div>
  <div id="circle4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess SVG would be better to create such kid of shapes.

Comment: Yes ok but how do we do that?

Comment: You will need to use an vector illustration program like Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape to create the SVG.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use svg quadratic bezier path to create such a shape.

```html
<svg version="1.1" height="400" width="400" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
      path:hover {
        fill: blue;
        transition: 0.5s ease;
      }
      path {
        transition: 0.5s ease;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0 0 Q5 3 10 0 7 5 10 10 5 7 0 10 3 5 0 0" stroke="none" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Nice one. SVG is much better when it comes to hover effect on such shapes.

Answer (score 1):

This would need some tweaking, but you may be able to use something like this.

It uses two elements (a parent and a child) in order to generate the shape you are looking for. This would work with a gradient background, although hit-testing would be somewhat off due to the way it's been generated.

```css
.one {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.two {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}
.one:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 50%;
  top: -42%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom: 30px solid red;
}
.two:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 200%;
  top: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  left: -136%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-right: 30px solid red;
}
.two:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 200%;
  top: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  right: -136%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-left: 30px solid red;
}
.one:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 50%;
  bottom: -42%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 30px solid red;
}

/*FOR DEMO ONLY*/


.one:hover:before{border-bottom-color:blue;}
.one:hover:after{border-top-color:blue;}
.one:hover .two{background:blue;}
.one:hover .two:before{border-right-color:blue;}
.one:hover .two:after{border-left-color:blue;}
.one,.two,.one:before,.one:after,.two:before,.two:after{transition:all 0.6s;}

html {
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(79, 79, 79);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(79, 79, 79, 1) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(79, 79, 79, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1)));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(79, 79, 79, 1) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(79, 79, 79, 1) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(79, 79, 79, 1) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(79, 79, 79, 1) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4f4f4f', endColorstr='#222222', GradientType=1);
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```